# How to display error type in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

in the following code

```
begin
 raise StandardError, 'message'
 #some code that raises a lot of exception
rescue StandardError
 #handle error
rescue OtherError
 #handle error
rescue YetAnotherError
 #handle error
end
```

I want to print a warning stating the type and the message of the error without adding print statement to each of the rescue clauses, like

```
begin
 raise StandardError, 'message'
 #some code that raises a lot of exception
rescue StandardError
 #handle error
rescue OtherError
 #handle error
rescue YetAnotherError
 #handle error
???
 print "An error of type #{???} happened, message is #{???}"
end
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
begin
  raise ArgumentError, "I'm a description"
rescue => e
  puts "An error of type #{e.class} happened, message is #{e.message}"
end
```

Prints: An error of type ArgumentError happened, message is I'm a description

Comment: And then if you still need specific handling for different types of errors, you can do that with a case..when.

Comment: Watch it, do not catch Exception unless you are completely aware of what it implies. Use rescue => ex instead(Convention over configuration) As a default cacher.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show the original backtrace and highlighting, you can take advantage of [Exception#full_message](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Exception.html#method-i-full_message):

> full_message(highlight: bool, order: [:top or :bottom]) → string
>
> Returns formatted string of exception. The returned string is formatted using the same format that Ruby uses when printing an uncaught exceptions to stderr.
>
> If *highlight* is `true` the default error handler will send the messages to a tty.
>
> *order* must be either of `:top` or `:bottom`, and places the error message and the innermost backtrace come at the top or the bottom.
>
> The default values of these options depend on `$stderr` and its `tty?` at the timing of a call.

```ruby
begin
  raise ArgumentError, "I'm a description"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e.full_message(highlight: true, order: :top)
end
```

Comment: `full_message` came on board in Rails 6. Not present in Rails 5.

Comment: @DavidHempy I'm refering at the ruby method `full_message`, not rails. Take a look at the link ! It looks like it came into ruby in the `2.5`

Comment: Ack...my bad.  You're right, @Ulysse BN . (We're on Ruby 2.4 / Rails 5.2. Most of my modern disappointments are from my Rails version, not the Ruby version)

Answer (score 5):

My version of printing errors with type, message and trace:

```
begin
    some_statement
rescue => e
    puts "Exception Occurred #{e.class}. Message: #{e.message}. Backtrace:  \n #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    Rails.logger.error "Exception Occurred #{e.class}. Message: #{e.message}. Backtrace:  \n #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
end
```

Comment: the question was about Ruby, not Rails, down-voting